# remove single back slash from string using R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have string

```
a <- c("COC1=CC(\\C=C\\C(=O)CC(=O)\\C=C\\C2=CC=C(O)C(OC)=C2)=CC=C1O")
```

I want to remove single backslash. I am expecting following result

```
COC1=CC(\C=C\C(=O)CC(=O)\C=C\C2=CC=C(O)C(OC)=C2)=CC=C1O
```

Comment: The backslashes are escaped characters.  Similar to how `\t` is a single character denoting a TAB, `\\` is a single character denoting a backslash.  If you remove one of the backslashes, you will then have a bunch of single characters `\C`, which will create an error as an unrecognized escape character.

Comment: 'cat' is for print, right?

Comment: @d.b this link explains how to gsub double backslash by forward slash. What I want is how to gsub double backslash by single backslash

Comment: There are no double backslashes in your string. Hint: don't believe what's printed.

Comment: @ Hong Ooi thanks that was very helpful